# How to animate the radius and the arc length of a pie chart in d3 (at the same time)?

Tags: d3.js, transition, pie-chart

I figured out how to change arc length of a pie chart with new values using d3 following [Bostock's Pie Chart Update](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5681842), but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to also animate the radius of the pic chart at the same time.

This a snippet of my current code:

```
pie_inner.value(function(d) {
    return d.toward === toward || toward === "both" ? d.spent : 0;
});

path_inner
    .data(function(d) {
        return pie_inner(d.data).map(function(m) {
            m.r = d.r;
            return m;
        })
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attrTween("d", function(d) {
        var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
        this._current = interpolate(0);
        return function(t) {
            arc_inner.innerRadius(d.r - thickness);
            arc_inner.outerRadius(d.r);

            return arc_inner(interpolate(t));
        };
    });
```

With this code the arc length animates to the new values nicely but the radius "jumps" to the new value.

I see that [this code](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4341574) animates both the arc length and the radius but it does it in sequence as opposed to the same time.

Comment: remove delay Bostock's example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting the radius using the function `outerRadius()`, but I figured out if I just set the property, then it works:

```
pie_inner.value(function(d) {
    return d.toward === toward || toward === "both" ? d.spent : 0;
});

path_inner
    .data(function(d) {
        return pie_inner(d.data).map(function(m) {
            m.r = d.r;
            return m;
        })
    })
    .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
            d.innerRadius = d.r - thickness;
            d.outerRadius = d.r;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            this._current = interpolate(0);

            return function(t) {
                return arc_inner(interpolate(t));
            };
        });
```